# Bash: Set up a new command on a new line without executing

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to write a BASH script to output a partially completed command which I can then add parameters to, hit ENTER and then run. I want this to be implemented completely in BASH.

e.g.

```
~> ./test.sh
~> ls -al <CURSOR POSITION HERE>
```

The only variable I've found that's close is the PROMPT_COMMAND variable, which when set inside test.sh to 'ls -al', will then immediately execute it once the script has exited.

Is there a way to stop the immediate execution, so I can add, say, *.log?

Comment: I don't understand how [How to prefill command line input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866005/how-to-prefill-command-line-input) is a duplicate. The answer there is written in C, not Bash.

Comment: @wjandrea It's the exact same question, and if anything, a new answer should be added there. "Duplicate" doesn't refer to the answers. Now we've ended up with two valid answers to the same question in two different places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
read -e -p"$PWD> " -i"ls -al " cmd; eval "$cmd"
```

Comment: Yep - that's exactly what I was after thanks!

Comment: Note, though, that this runs the command in a new shell, not the current shell.

Comment: @chepner: Ok I modified the suggestion to use `eval` instead.

Comment: Rather than display `cmd` as part of the prompt, pass it as the argument to the `-i` option. That places the value on the command line itself, which the user can edit, and includes it in the final value of `opt`.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks for the tip. The questioner didn't specify wether or not he wants to have that part editable, but the command gets simpler that way so I go for it.